# How can we add a button over collection view using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, button, collectionview

I have a `UICollectionViewController` in my `main.storyboard`.
I want to add a circle button to redirect to new page, But in `storyboard` is it possible to drag a button over `UICollectionView`? I don't know about footer how can we achieve.

It should looks like `UICollectionView` is scrolling and button will be over the collection view, I mean no effect on button.

Comment: It's probably easiest if you embed the UICollectionViewController in a UINavigationController so you can put a UIBarButton in the navigation bar.

Comment: have you tried to add button programmatically ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using a UICollectionViewController? You have to switch to UIViewController implementing UICollectionViewDataSource and UICollectionViewDelegate. Then you place UICollectionView there and UIButton over it so there will be "root" UIView and those two views underneath it. Connect all required outlets and actions and you are done.

Comment: I am using UICollectionViewController.
I have done everything now.
But want to add a button only.
Is it possible?

Comment: Create new scene. Cut the collection view and paste into new scene.

Comment: Ok let me check.
Thanks

Comment: You will also have to change view controller code but it should not be much bother. The main thing is that you will have to add collectionView outlet.

Comment: Thanks to suggest.
Done.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can do it,

If using `UIViewController` Put your button above collectionview like this,

[image]

If using `UICollectionViewContoller`, you can't add button to storyboard, you need to add button programmatically.
Call below function in `viewDidLoad()`.

```
fileprivate func addButton(){
    let button = UIButton()
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setTitle("Button", for: UIControlState.normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: UIControlState.normal)
    self.view.addSubview(button)
    button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
}
```

Comment: But I am using UICollectionViewController.

Comment: Ok, please update your question accordingly so others can get it, and try to use UIViewController if you want's to add more components apart from collection view.

Comment: Please use constraints in your example instead of frame manipulations. You are giving bad example to newbies.

Comment: I created UI Again.
And added a button.
Its working.

Thanks